# :param [変数名]:の役割について、return以下が空白の時の挙動について

Tags: python

①    `:param [変数名]:`
はコード中でどんな役割をするのでしょうか？

日本語サイトであれば、
（https://qiita.com/methane/items/e95c578c3d8fc5f1f62e）（python paramで検索しヒット）
が、おそらく参考になると思うのですが、読んでもいまいちつかめません。
少しかみ砕いた説明が欲しいです。

文脈として全コードを以下に掲載します。

```
def bottles_of_beer(bob):
    """ Prints Bottle of Beer on the Wall lyrics.

    :param bob: Must be a positive integer.
    """
    if bob<1:
        print("""No more bottle of beer on the wall.
              No more bottles of beer.""")
        return

    tmp=bob
    bob-=1
    print("""{} bottles of beer on the wall.
          {} bottles of beer.
          Take one down,pass it around,
          {} bottles of beer on the wall.
          """.format(tmp,tmp,bob))
    bottles_of_beer(bob)

bottles_of_beer(99)
```

②また、このコードでreturn以下が空白となっていますが、デフォルト（？）では何を実行すべきという意味になるのでしょうか？

Comment: `②また、このコードでreturn以下が空白となっていますが、デフォルト（？）では何を実行すべきという意味になるのでしょうか？`は、`return 1`など`return`に引数を持つ場合があるのに、本コードでは`return`のみで引数がないという意味でしょうか?それとも`return`のあとに空行があるという意味でしょうか?

Comment: @tanalab2 さん、returnのみで引数がないという意味です。

Comment: 承知しました。コメントを踏まえ②についてのみ回答を追加しました。ご確認下さい。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:param [変数名]:`の記述は **docstring** と呼ばれるコメント記法の一つです。

コメントなのでプログラムの動作に直接の影響は与えませんが、関数の使い方などを決められたフォーマットで記述しておくことで、IDEなどから参照したり、ドキュメント出力ができるようです。
記法にはいくつかスタイルがあって、質問の例に挙げられたものは「reStructuredText(reST)スタイル」と呼ばれるもののようです。

参考：
[可読性を上げるための、docstringの書き方を学ぶ（NumPyスタイル）](https://qiita.com/simonritchie/items/49e0813508cad4876b5a)
[Pythonのdocstring（ドキュメンテーション文字列）の書き方](https://note.nkmk.me/python-docstring/)

---

質問のコードについては**再帰呼出し**をしています。

一番最後の行で「初期値=99」を指定して一度呼び出すと、1ずつ減らしながら(=ビールを飲みながら)再帰呼出しを繰り返し、`return`の部分に処理が移るのは「数字が`0`になったとき=ビールが無くなったとき」です。
`param`の説明もこのため「正の整数」を指定しろとなっていますね。

Comment: `#`以外にもそんな記述方法があるとは驚きです。これを機に他のコメントの記法も学んでいきます。

Comment: 念のため補足しておくと`#`は単一行のコメント、質問の例に上がっている`:param`は前後をダブルクォート3つで括られており、これが複数行コメントの扱いになっています。`:param`がコメントなわけではないのでご注意を。 参考： [Pythonでのコメントアウトの書き方](https://uxmilk.jp/8847)

Answer (score 0):

`:param <type> <variable>: <description>` はSphinxで処理されるドキュメントの記法で、情報フィールドリストと言います。

http://www.sphinx-doc.org/ja/master/usage/restructuredtext/domains.html#info-field-lists

Pythonの多くのライブラリはSphinxでドキュメント生成を行っているため、docstringの書き方の中にも情報フィールドリストが広く使われています。また、PyCharmなどのIDEもこの情報フィールドリストを解釈してくれます。このような理由から、Sphinxを使わないプロジェクトのdocstringであっても情報フィールドリストの書き方を踏襲しているプロジェクトもあります。

Comment: Pythonの書き方以外にもプログラマーが一般的に使っている周辺ソフトなどの知識も併せて必要となるのですね・・・

Comment: P.S.「独学プログラマー Python言語の基本から仕事のやり方まで」いつも大変お世話になっております。

Answer (score 0):

> ②また、このコードでreturn以下が空白となっていますが、デフォルト（？）では何を実行すべきという意味になるのでしょうか？

関数のなかで、`return`のみが実行された場合、呼出元に`None`が返却されます。
例としては、以下になります。

```
# 1を返却する関数
def myfunc01():
    return 1

# 実行すると1が返却され表示される
print(myfunc01())  #=> 1

# 何も返却しない関数
def myfunc02():
    return

# 実行するとNoneが返却され表示される
print(myfunc02()) #=> None
```

Comment: return以外に、同様の働きをするものは何かありますか？ループではないので`break`は使えませんし、、、

Comment: また、`None`を返し続けている、と思ったのですが処理は止まっている状態なのでしょうか？

Comment: @u_1 さん、 cubickさんが回答されているように、**再帰呼出し**により繰り返し処理をしています。再帰の終了条件が`bob<1`の時で、その場合のみ`None`を返却しています。

Comment: 勘違いをしていました。申し訳ございません。

Comment: ifに処理が移ったら繰り返しが終了ということを忘れていました。